# I need to count the number of rows in a table in oracle script

Tags: oracle

I need to count the number of rows in a table in oracle server sql script. Any help would be great help.

Comment: `select count(*) from yourtable`?

Comment: Just FYI - Google returns about 780 **thousand** results for "sql count rows in table".

Comment: I hate when newbies get downvoted. Yes, it's an obvious question, but we were all beginners once.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM someTable;
```

Will return the total number of rows in the table.

Answer (score 0):

well, in case you want to use it in a procedure, storing in a variable, can do this,

```
declare
l_count number;
begin
select count(*) into l_count from table_name;
dbms_output.put_line('the no of rows in table : '|| l_count);
end;
/
```